# SQL Results Pagination

Tags: sql, pagination

I'm having a bit of trouble paginating my sql query results using PHP. I have tried a few different solutions but have had no success so far. Would someone be able to help me please? Below is my current code I use to display all results however I'd like them splitting into pages of 50.

```
<?
 //query
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names"); 

 //counts_result 
 $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 {

 echo "ERROR"; 
 }

else {
    echo "<div class='search_result_output'>
    SEARCH SUCCESS 
    </div><hr>";
}

?>
<?

 //display results 
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 {
 echo "<div class='panel panel-default'>";
 echo "<div class='panel-heading'>";
 echo "<h4 class='panel-title'>";
 echo $result['name'];
 echo "</h4>";
 echo "</div>";
 echo "<div class='game_actions' style='float:right; margin-top:-40px; margin-right:10px;'>";
 echo "<a data-toggle='collapse' class='btn btn-custom' data-parent='#accordion' href='#".$result['id']."' title='More Info on ".$result['name']."'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></a>";
 echo "</div>";
 echo "<div id='".$result['id']."' class='panel-collapse collapse'>";
 echo "<div class='panel-body'>";
 echo $result['name'];;
 echo "</div>";
 echo "</div>";
 echo "</div>";
 }
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names");
```

instead use this:

```
$page = (isset($_GET["page"])) ? $_GET["page"] : "0";

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names limit ".$page.", 50");
```

Display your links accordingly; add the page value to them. Your paging depends on the get parameter named "page".

EDIT:

If you want to display a link pointing to the 5th page, for instance, then:

```
echo '<a href="yoururl?page='.(4 * 50).'">5</a>';
```

4 * 50 = page index * page size. Page index is 4, as on the first page you have no offset. It is difficult to add any more help, since I do not know what kind of paging you need. However, this edit should help you to start solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Lajos Arpad. I have edited my code. Would you able to give more info on actually displaying the pagination? I think that is what I keep messing up on :(

Comment: I am glad I could help you. If my answer solves your problem, then please consider accepting it. If it is not solving the problem, then please tell me how can I help you further.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this query and then just just change parameter i.e (3 and 8)

Select * from
(select Id,Name ,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Id) as RowNum from Person.dbo.pers 
) tbl
Where tbl.RowNum between 3 and 8

it gets 3 to 8 rows